# How to display ESO Harps s1d fits file? (Python)

Tags: python, astropy, astronomy, fits, specutils

Hi I am looking to plot a spectra on python of a fits file. ESO has a guide on how to display 1D spectra and a code that should work which is the following:

```
import sys
from astropy.io import fits as pyfits
import numpy as np
#

hdulist = pyfits.open( "your_1d_spectrum_here.fits" )

# print column information
hdulist[1].columns

# get to the data part (in extension 1)
scidata = hdulist[1].data

wave = scidata[0][0]
arr1 = scidata[0][1]
arr2 = scidata[0][2]
# etc.
# where arr1 will contain the data corresponding to the column named: hdulist[1].columns[1]
# where arr2 will contain the data corresponding to the column named: hdulist[1].columns[2]
# etc.

# To plot using maptplotlib:

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(wave, arr1)

plt.show()
```

but when putting this code in and using the s1d file I have I get IndexError: list index out of range

The HDUlist.info() consists one one primary HDU with index 0

```
No.    Name      Ver    Type      Cards   Dimensions   Format
0  PRIMARY       1 PrimaryHDU    3051   (313088,)   float32
```

and printing this data shows that it is a 1d array:
[ 45.182148   71.06376     3.1499128 ... 631.7653    628.2799
632.91364  ]

so I'm clueless on how to plot this spectra as it's only 1d.

Eso also has a more complicated code to plot the spectra as found on the website https://archive.eso.org/cms/eso-data/help/1dspectra.html#Python  the file is the 1dspectrum.py which can be downloaded. Once I've inputted my file on there, I get an index error too which can be seen in the gyazo https://gyazo.com/e30a1f39e5f33821b5a5c54f3939a028

Attempted Iguananaut's solution
with this as the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from astropy.io import fits
from astropy.units import u
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import specutils

f = fits.open('C:/Users/Rp199/Desktop/J0608_59_harps_2018/HARPS.2018-05-23T23_44_45.005_s1d_A.fits')
f.info()

No.    Name      Ver    Type      Cards   Dimensions   Format
  0  PRIMARY       1 PrimaryHDU    3055   (313093,)   float32
```

Checked the headers and they were the same so I deleted BUNIT and changed CTYPE1 to CUNIT1

```
del header['BUNIT']
header['CTYPE1'] = header['CUNIT1']
del header['CTYPE1']
```

Then I tried to use spectrum1D.read

```
spec = specutils.Spectrum1D.read(f)
spec
```

which gives me the following error

```
IORegistryError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-62aceed26d07> in <module>
----> 1 spec = specutils.Spectrum1D.read(f)
      2 spec

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\astropy\nddata\mixins\ndio.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
     54 
     55     def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
---> 56         return registry.read(self._cls, *args, **kwargs)
     57 
     58 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\astropy\io\registry.py in read(cls, format, *args, **kwargs)
    517                     fileobj = args[0]
    518 
--> 519             format = _get_valid_format(
    520                 'read', cls, path, fileobj, args, kwargs)
    521 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\astropy\io\registry.py in _get_valid_format(mode, cls, path, fileobj, args, kwargs)
    597     if len(valid_formats) == 0:
    598         format_table_str = _get_format_table_str(cls, mode.capitalize())
--> 599         raise IORegistryError("Format could not be identified based on the"
    600                               " file name or contents, please provide a"
    601                               " 'format' argument.\n"

IORegistryError: Format could not be identified based on the file name or contents, please provide a 'format' argument.
The available formats are:
      Format      Read Write Auto-identify
----------------- ---- ----- -------------
    APOGEE apStar  Yes    No           Yes
   APOGEE apVisit  Yes    No           Yes
APOGEE aspcapStar  Yes    No           Yes
            ASCII  Yes    No           Yes
             ECSV  Yes    No           Yes
          HST/COS  Yes    No           Yes
         HST/STIS  Yes    No           Yes
             IPAC  Yes    No           Yes
         JWST s2d  Yes    No           Yes
         JWST s3d  Yes    No           Yes
         JWST x1d  Yes    No           Yes
 SDSS-I/II spSpec  Yes    No           Yes
 SDSS-III/IV spec  Yes    No           Yes
 Subaru-pfsObject  Yes    No           Yes
             iraf  Yes    No           Yes
      muscles-sed  Yes    No           Yes
     tabular-fits  Yes   Yes           Yes
       wcs1d-fits  Yes    No           Yes
```

I made the assumption that because my file is a s1d.fits file the format would be wcs1d-fits? I tried to look through the headers in Fits viewer to identify a format but couldn't find anything. When putting in wcs1d-fits as the format:

```
spec = specutils.Spectrum1D.read(f, format="wcs1d-fits")
spec
```

I am returned this,

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-c038104effad> in <module>
----> 1 spec = specutils.Spectrum1D.read(f, format="wcs1d-fits")
      2 spec

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\astropy\nddata\mixins\ndio.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
     54 
     55     def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
---> 56         return registry.read(self._cls, *args, **kwargs)
     57 
     58 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\astropy\io\registry.py in read(cls, format, *args, **kwargs)
    521 
    522         reader = get_reader(format, cls)
--> 523         data = reader(*args, **kwargs)
    524 
    525         if not isinstance(data, cls):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\specutils\io\default_loaders\wcs_fits.py in wcs1d_fits_loader(file_name, spectral_axis_unit, flux_unit, hdu_idx, **kwargs)
     63     logging.info("Spectrum file looks like wcs1d-fits")
     64 
---> 65     with fits.open(file_name, **kwargs) as hdulist:
     66         header = hdulist[hdu_idx].header
     67         wcs = WCS(header)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\astropy\io\fits\hdu\hdulist.py in fitsopen(name, mode, memmap, save_backup, cache, lazy_load_hdus, **kwargs)
    162         raise ValueError(f'Empty filename: {name!r}')
    163 
--> 164     return HDUList.fromfile(name, mode, memmap, save_backup, cache,
    165                             lazy_load_hdus, **kwargs)
    166 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\astropy\io\fits\hdu\hdulist.py in fromfile(cls, fileobj, mode, memmap, save_backup, cache, lazy_load_hdus, **kwargs)
    401         """
    402 
--> 403         return cls._readfrom(fileobj=fileobj, mode=mode, memmap=memmap,
    404                              save_backup=save_backup, cache=cache,
    405                              lazy_load_hdus=lazy_load_hdus, **kwargs)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\astropy\io\fits\hdu\hdulist.py in _readfrom(cls, fileobj, data, mode, memmap, save_backup, cache, lazy_load_hdus, **kwargs)
   1052             if not isinstance(fileobj, _File):
   1053                 # instantiate a FITS file object (ffo)
-> 1054                 fileobj = _File(fileobj, mode=mode, memmap=memmap, cache=cache)
   1055             # The Astropy mode is determined by the _File initializer if the
   1056             # supplied mode was None

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\astropy\utils\decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    533                     warnings.warn(message, warning_type, stacklevel=2)
    534 
--> 535             return function(*args, **kwargs)
    536 
    537         return wrapper

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\astropy\io\fits\file.py in __init__(self, fileobj, mode, memmap, overwrite, cache)
    193             self._open_filename(fileobj, mode, overwrite)
    194         else:
--> 195             self._open_filelike(fileobj, mode, overwrite)
    196 
    197         self.fileobj_mode = fileobj_mode(self._file)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\astropy\io\fits\file.py in _open_filelike(self, fileobj, mode, overwrite)
    544 
    545         if mode == 'ostream':
--> 546             self._overwrite_existing(overwrite, fileobj, False)
    547 
    548         # Any "writeable" mode requires a write() method on the file object

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\astropy\io\fits\file.py in _overwrite_existing(self, overwrite, fileobj, closed)
    442         # The file will be overwritten...
    443         if ((self.file_like and hasattr(fileobj, 'len') and fileobj.len > 0) or
--> 444                 (os.path.exists(self.name) and os.path.getsize(self.name) != 0)):
    445             if overwrite:
    446                 if self.file_like and hasattr(fileobj, 'truncate'):

~\anaconda3\lib\genericpath.py in exists(path)
     17     """Test whether a path exists.  Returns False for broken symbolic links"""
     18     try:
---> 19         os.stat(path)
     20     except (OSError, ValueError):
     21         return False

TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not method
```

Comment: Hello--when asking for help with an error in Python code, please provide the full traceback (everything from `Traceback (most recent call last):` through to the exception message itself.  This helps provide context as to exactly where the error is coming from.  Please copy and paste it as text into the question, and not as a screenshot.

Comment: In your update you showed making the same manipulations to the header that I made in my example.  To be clear, those were specific to the one file I happened to look at.  You need to look at the headers of the file you're trying to read and determine whether or not it makes sense.  It's possible that none of the existing format readers in specutils can understand it.  If you're not sure how to interpret the header please post at least a portion of it (maybe the first 50 keywords or so).

Comment: I also just realized based on your traceback that you're using an older version of specutils which might be part of the problem.  In the version you're using it doesn't support passing an open FITS file to `Spectrum1D.read` in this case.  You need to call `Spectrum1D.read(filename)`.  This is unfortunate because it means you can't have an opportunity to first correct defects in the header before passing it to `Spectrum1D.read()` like I did in my example, so it would be better to upgrade specutils to the latest version.

Comment: Thank you, it seemed that updating specutils worked and allows me to use it. However when using it I receive the following warning
`WARNING: FITSFixedWarning: RADECSYS= 'FK5 ' / Coordinate reference frame 
the RADECSYS keyword is deprecated, use RADESYSa. [astropy.wcs.wcs]
WARNING:astropy:FITSFixedWarning: RADECSYS= 'FK5 ' / Coordinate reference frame 
the RADECSYS keyword is deprecated, use RADESYSa.
`
can i just ignore this when using specutils to plot the spectra?

Comment: Yes, that's a warning that the file is using outdated WCS semantics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a look at a random spectrum downloaded from [this page](https://www.eso.org/sci/facilities/lasilla/instruments/harps/inst/monitoring/sun.html).  Indeed it contains only one HDU so you will get an `IndexError` if you try to access data from an HDU that does not exist.

The code you linked to might be old (it is on an "archive" page after all) and is also merely an example, not necessarily appropriate for plotting data from any FITS file.

The [specutils](https://specutils.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spectrum1d.html) package has many utilities for analyzing and plotting 1D spectra.  It can also read spectra from many common FITS formats without having to do too much manually.

Here's what I did.  First I opened the file, this one in particular:

```py
>>> f = fits.open('https://www.eso.org/sci/facilities/lasilla/instruments/harps/inst/monitoring/sundata/ceres_2006-05-22_s1d.fits')
>>> f.info()
f = fits.open('https://www.eso.org/sci/facilities/lasilla/instruments/harps/inst/monitoring/sundata/ceres_2006-05-22_s1d.fits')
```

Looking at the header, especially the first dozen or so header keywords, can give us a lot of clues as to how the data in the file is to be interpreted:

```
>>> header = f[0].header
>>> header[:12]
SIMPLE  =                    T / file does conform to FITS standard             
BITPIX  =                  -32 / number of bits per data pixel                  
NAXIS   =                    1 / number of data axes                            
NAXIS1  =               313237 / length of data axis 1                          
EXTEND  =                    T / FITS dataset may contain extensions            
COMMENT   FITS (Flexible Image Transport System) format is defined in 'Astronomy
COMMENT   and Astrophysics', volume 376, page 359; bibcode: 2001A&A...376..359H 
CRPIX1  =                   1. / Reference pixel                                
CRVAL1  =              3781.19 / Coordinate at reference pixel                  
CDELT1  =                 0.01 / Coordinate increment par pixel                 
CTYPE1  = 'Angstrom'           / Units of coordinate                            
BUNIT   = 'Relative Flux'      / Units of data values
```

We can infer from `BUNIT = 'Relative Flux'` that the single array in the file contains flux values in some unspecified unit (this file is also malformatted in a few ways but I'll get to that later).

It doesn't contain a spectral array, instead the spectrum just starts from 3781.19 Å, at the first pixel (we get this from `CRVAL1` and `CRPIX1`; keep in mind `CRPIXn`, like other indices in FITS files, uses Fortran-style indexing which starts with 1, as opposed to C/Python which starts at 0, so this is saying the 0-th element of the array is the flux of the spectrum at 3781.19 Å).

It also says `CDELT1 = 0.01 / Coordinate increment par pixel` so every pixel is +0.01 Å.

So we could do:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from astropy.units import u
>>> flux = f[0].data
>>> ref = header['CRVAL1']
>>> step = header['CDELT1']
>>> wave = np.arange(ref, ref + (len(flux) * step), step) * u.AA
>>> plt.plot(wave, flux)
```

Specutils can in principle make this easier though.  To read a `Spectrum1D` from a FITS file--if it's in a supported format--you can do:

```py
>>> from specutils import Spectrum1D
>>> spec = Spectrum1D.read(f)
```

Unfortunately in this case Specutils failed to read the file and I got:

```
ValueError: 'Relative Flux' did not parse as unit: At col 0, Relative is not a valid unit.  If this is meant to be a custom unit, define it with 'u.def_unit'. To have it recognized inside a file reader or other code, enable it with 'u.add_enabled_units'. For details, see https://docs.astropy.org/en/latest/units/combining_and_defining.html
```

This is part of what I meant when I wrote earlier that the file is malformatted.  "Relative Flux" is not a valid, known name for any unit that would go in the `BUNIT` header of a FITS file.  Since I don't know what the flux units are supposed to be in this case, I just deleted it:

```py
>>> del header['BUNIT']
```

A further problem with this file is that it isn't using the `CTYPE1` keyword correctly.  This should be `CUNIT1`.  I don't know why they did this.  I again updated the header:

```py
>>> header['CUNIT1'] = header['CTYPE1]
>>> del header['CTYPE1']
```

Now it works:

```py
>>> spec = Spectrum1D.read(f)
>>> spec
<Spectrum1D(flux=<Quantity [0.0043928 , 0.00500706, 0.00511265, ..., 0.00435138, 0.00433926,
           0.00433523]>, spectral_axis=<SpectralAxis [3781.19, 3781.2 , 3781.21, ..., 6913.53, 6913.54, 6913.55] Angstrom>)>
```

and can be plotted like (just following the specutils documentation):

```py
>>> from astropy.visualization import quantity_support
>>> quantity_support()
>>> fig, ax = plt.subplots()
>>> ax.step(spec.spectral_axis, spec.flux)
>>> fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Iguananaut, thanks for the response. I have attempted to follow and reproduce the procedure you have shown me on my own code however when using spectrum1D.read I am prompted to enter a format of the file as it couldn't be identified. I have edited the post posted a full traceback of what comes up (I'm not too familiar on how to use this forum sorry) and my attempt on selecting the format. Could you give it a read please and let me know what is wrong?

Comment: In the update you posted what is `sd1test`?  It appears to be a method somehow.  See the error message "TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not *method*"

Comment: s1dtest is just the equivalent of f in your response `s1dtest = fits.open(myfile.fits)`

I changed it to just f like in your response and received the same traceback

Comment: Can you please update your question with the *exact* steps you took?

Comment: Has been updated with the exact steps, if anything is unclear please let me know

Comment: I have replied on the main thread, thank you for your help, there is an error I've posted as a comment in the main thread.